# Javascript animation timing

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm writing a program in Javascript with Raphael to get one path to be drawn from where another one ends. 
I've tried a number of ways and finally got it to connect using the BBox coordinates as the lines I'm using are relatively straight. I'm sure there's probably another (better) way, but everything I've tried hasn't worked.

The problem I'm having now is that when I run the program in the browser, on some occasions the two lines will connect at the right point and on other occasions when I refresh it, it won't. I'm really confused as I didn't change anything.

I thought it might be something to do with the timing, so I added a delay, but that didn't work, although it will only draw the second line if the delay is in place and long enough.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
window.onload = function(){
var paper = new Raphael(100,0,2000,2000);
var line1 = paper.path("m 300 400 l 100 200");

function lines(){
    line1.animate({"transform":"r102 t120 20"});
}

setTimeout(function box1(){
    var bbox = line1.getBBox();
    var line2 = paper.path("m"+[bbox.x]+" "+[bbox.y2]+"l 200 100");
}, 1000000000000000);

lines();
box1();

};
```

Comment: I think you may have to explain better what you are trying to achieve overall with the animation, timing and each line, and why you are using animate.

Comment: The animate is there so I can move the first line to any point and the other one will follow it, that's what I want to achieve with this. I thought I could use this to re-draw my art in various positions. In all honesty I'm more of an artist than a programmer, I've only been learning Javascript for a few weeks, so I'm sure my code has a lot of room for improvement, but my research has turned up nothing about the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now. I've used .onAnimation to delay the drawing of the second line and it works now.

i.e.

```
function lines(){
    line1.animate({"transform":"r62t40 20"}).onAnimation(function (){
        var bbox = line1.getBBox();
        var line2 = paper.path("m"+[bbox.x]+" "+[bbox.y2]+"l 200 100");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you are animating still. I would put them together in a set and rotate around a point. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbvm/

```
var paper = new Raphael(100,0,2000,2000);
var line1 = paper.path("M300 400 l100 200");
var line2 = paper.path("M400 600 l200 100");
var set = paper.set();
set.push( line1, line2 );
set.transform('r50,200,200');
```